# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_keydown' in Maven project

Tags: python, maven, robotframework, attributeerror, pyautogui

I have problem with puautogui python library.
But when I use the library in command line or in robot framework (without maven), then all works fine. But I get this problem when I use the library in robot framework in Maven project.

Do you know what should I do?

Python Code:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite('first')
pyautogui.typewrite(['down'])
pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it works now..
When maven unzipped the libraries to file, then compiled all library include pyautogui, and there should are created compiled files, and modules should have also **module$py.class** file. But the one (puautogui_win.py) doesn't.
So in *init*.py I added `import pyautogui.pyautogui_win` but there was only `import pyautogui.pyautogui_win as platformModule`